# Multi-part Form with File Input JQuery Mobile

Tags: html, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, blobstore, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to  create a JQuery Mobile page that uploads a video to the Google App Engine Blobstore along with associated title, description, etc.

Here's the HTML of the form.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ upload_url }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false">
  <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" id="basic" value="" data-ajax="false" />
  <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description" id="basic" value="" data-ajax="false" />
  <input type="file" data-ajax="false" name="file" id="file">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="sumbit" data-theme="b" data-ajax="false">
</form>
```

The HTML is generated in Google App Engine using this code.

```
class MobileUploadPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/uploadvideo')
    template_values = {
      'upload_url': upload_url,
    }

    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('mobileUpload.html')
    self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
```

The upload URL you see as the action of the form is generated by the blobstore using the following handler.

```
class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
  def post(self):
  upload = self.get_uploads()[0]
  video = Videos(content=upload.key())
  video.title = self.request.get('title')
  video.description = self.request.get('description')
  video.ratingDown = 0
  video.ratingUp = 0
  video.creator = users.get_current_user().nickname()
  uniuqeIDFound = False
  newID = random.randint(1000,9999)
  while(uniuqeIDFound == False):
    vids = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * "
                       "FROM Videos ")

    uniuqeIDFound = True
    for v in vids:
      if (v.videoID == newID):
        newID = random.randint(1,10000)
        uniuqeIDFound = False
  video.videoID = newID
  db.put(video)
  self.redirect('/home')
```

The upload URL is generated properly and appears on the page. On the browser version of our site, it works perfectly. However, when trying to upload a video from an iPhone via this JQM mobile page to the blobstore, the form does not submit.

In the JQM documentation, it says that multi-part form input with a file doesn't work with AJAX and so you should add the data-ajax=false tag to the parent form. I've done that but it doesn't seem to help.

Can anyone see why?

Comment: According to the jQuery Mobile docs on [default configurations](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html), `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled` defaults to `true`. This setting as `true` intercepts form submissions and sends XML HTTP requests instead. Have you retried this setting `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled` to `false` as suggested by Jay@? In addition, can you also include what happens in [Safari's Web Inspector for iPhone](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787) and the related log if a form request is in fact submitted?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
```

or

```
$.mobile.ajaxFormsEnabled = false;
```

Also you can take a look at specific file upload plugins:

http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php

or

https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-Custom-File-Input